# Maps API v3 Marker disappears on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Firstly, although there are several other similar issues on here I can't tailor them to my own code - the issues seem to still originate from elsewhere.

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API v3 to move the marker when you click anywhere on the map. I've already set it up so you can drag the marker, but I can't get the click to work. As you can see in my code, I've attempted this already.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.9,-2.08);

var myOptions = {
 zoom: 13,
 center: myLatlng,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 draggable: true,
 position: myLatlng,
 map: map,
 title: "Your location"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (overlay, point) {
 document.getElementById("P102_LATITUDE").value = this.getPosition().lat();
 document.getElementById("P102_LONGITUDE").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay, point) {
 marker.setPosition(event.latlng); 
 document.getElementById("P102_LATITUDE").value = this.getPosition().lat();
 document.getElementById("P102_LONGITUDE").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error with [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/LzezLgtz/), when I click to move the marker:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on this line:

```
document.getElementById("P102_LATITUDE").value = this.getPosition().lat();
```

The `this` in a **map** click event is the map.  You are using the click event incorrectly (looks like you got that code from a Google Maps Javascript API v2 example).  The [google.maps.eventMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) object only has one property .latLng (javascript is case sensitive):

```
 
Properties  Type    Description
latLng      LatLng  The latitude/longitude that was below the cursor when the event occurred.
```

and the [function signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) is:

> click MouseEvent  This event is fired when the user clicks on the map (but not when they click on a marker or infowindow).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
 marker.setPosition(event.latLng); 
 document.getElementById("P102_LATITUDE").value = marker.getPosition().lat();
 document.getElementById("P102_LONGITUDE").value = marker.getPosition().lng();
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzezLgtz/2/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.9, -2.08);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "Your location"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("P102_LATITUDE").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("P102_LONGITUDE").value = this.getPosition().lng();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    document.getElementById("P102_LATITUDE").value = marker.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("P102_LONGITUDE").value = marker.getPosition().lng();
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="P102_LATITUDE" />
<input id="P102_LONGITUDE" />
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for your help, I didn't think the error would be in that line.