# markerimage disappears after a particular position in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

i have kept the marker image draggable it disappears after a particular position. I have attached a screenshot to represent the problem.

```
markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../img/marker.png', null, null,null,new google.maps.Size(14, 14));

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(locations[idx][2],locations[idx][3]),
    icon : markerImage,
    draggable : isDraggable,
    map : panorama
});
```

Please don't say google maps size is causing the problem. I have checked it is not causing the problem.

[Problem Image](http://prntscr.com/6n5t61)

Comment: The `MarkerImage` class is deprecated, you should use the [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) class instead

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the code of your listeners to allow move the marker, I also assume `isDraggable` is `true` sometimes:

```
  // listener for the MAP that moves marker on click
  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'click', function(event) {
      marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
  });
```

[CHECK THIS WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LzezLgtz/2/) and [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301341/maps-api-v3-marker-disappears-on-click)